# how to provide a click handler in JQCloud

Tags: jquery, tag-cloud

I am using JQCloud for building a tagcloud. It's nice and easy and meets my user's visual criteria. I would like to have a click handler invoked when user clicks on a word:

```
var tag_list = new Array();
for ( var i = 0; i < stuff.length; ++i ) {
    var x = stuff[i];
    tag_list.push({
            text: x.NAME,
            weight: x.COUNT,
            //link: this.mkUrl(x),
            click: function() { alert("it worked for " + x.NAME); },
            html: {title: this.mkTooltip(x)}
    });
}
$("#"+containerdivname).append( $("<div></div>", {id:"wordcloud"}));
$("#"+containerdivname).children("#wordcloud").jQCloud( tag_list );
```

The word cloud renders fine, has proper tooltip, but does not show an alert box on click. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: syntax for the click-handler looks ok. Can you prove a working demo on jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: @soderslatt Thanks, here is one: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6348/5/ It (sorry, I haven't used either of these tools before. It does look kinda ugly but tooltip does show ok.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handlers in JQCloud is supposed to be specified like this:

```
handlers : {click: function() { alert("it worked for" + x.NAME); }}
```

working example, http://jsfiddle.net/Q6348/7/

Comment: A step closer, thanks. But for some reason it always says "worked for n4" which is the last word in the list. How can I get it to zero in on that particular row?

Answer (score 2):

A little different and maybe a easier way to implement it would be, to build your array like this:

```
var stuff = [];
stuff.push({"text":"n1","weight":23,"handlers" : {click: function(res) { alert("it worked for"+res.target.textContent);}}})
```

This will give you the value of the node you clicked on.

Or if you want to pass it to a function, you can use it like this:

```
stuff.push({"text":"n1","weight":23,"handlers" : {click: function(res) { run(res) }}})

function run(res){
alert("it worked for"+res.target.textContent);
}
```

Hope this solution helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can always add a standard jquery handler for your click:

```
$(document).on('click', '#container-id .jqcloud-word', function() {
    var word_value = $(this).val();
    console.log(word_value);
});
```